# The relation between range and $\sin\theta$ or $\sin(2\theta)$ in a projectile motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

I was doing a physics lab report about projectile motion. The lab is about a ball thrown at different angles to the ground.

I am measuring the range of the ball, and after the measure I need to do the graph. My teacher told me my graph should be range on y-axis and $\sin\theta$ on x-axis, I really confused about this.

What on my research is that:

$$ R=u^2 \frac{\sin(2\theta)}{g} $$

which also equal to:

$$ R=u^2 \frac{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{g} $$

So I want to know the relation between range and $\sin\theta$, like why I should use $\sin\theta$ instead of just the angle or $\sin(2\theta)$.

What is $\sin\theta$ meaning in this experiment?

Comment: You get a maximum $R$ value at a particular $\sin (\theta)$. From your graph you can determine the corresponding value for $\theta$ and so you can deduce what value of $\theta$ maximizes the range of a projectile. Seems to me that it would have been easier if you plot $R$ versus $\sin (2\theta )$ since this also is a maximum when $\theta =\frac{\pi}{4}$ ($45^\circ$).

Comment: This is an interesting question. I think I know the answer but could not come out with it. I would really like to find out the physical insight behind it.

Comment: Do you know how the range formula for R was derived? What are the inputs to the problem? It might help to draw a picture of the complete trajectory and sketch some details associated with the launch point and the impact point. Sometimes, the dependent variable is chosen because it might have a more physical meaning than another variable or because it might be easier to analyze than another variable.